# HTML: Div not able to be clicked (Hyperlink)

Tags: html, css, css-position, anchor, pseudo-element

I've currently encountered a problem wherein I am not able to click the link that I've provided for my HTML file. I'm currently in a school project that needs the periodic table of atomic numbers 61-90.

I tried  to add simple designs that helps the website give a clean look, then I tried to add a hyperlink so it may lead to another webpage which will give details about the  specific element.

I have not yet found any solutions that I can understand, ***I am still quite new to HTML, and to this website (hehe)***, so can you guys help me out on this? **Thanks in advance!**
Here are the codes that I've used:

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: chocolate;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
div:hover:before {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0);
}
```

```html
<div><a href=https://www.google.com/>Nd</a></div>
<div>Pm</div>
<div>Sm</div>
<div>Eu</div>
<div>Gd</div>
<div>Tb</div>
<div>Dy</div>
<div>Ho</div>
<div>Er</div>
<div>Tm</div>
<div>Yb</div>
<div>Lu</div>
<div>Ac</div>
<div>Th</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't click on the `anchor` element as it is stacked behind the `before` element.

(The `before` element is `absolute` and hence is stacked above the `a` element for which position is not specified, so becoming `static` position- which is the default for any element )

So here is a fix- make it a positioned element by adding say:

```
div a {
 position: relative;
}
```

and now the link will be clickable.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: chocolate;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
div:hover:before {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0);
}
div a {
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div><a href=https://www.google.com/">Nd</a></div>
<div>Pm</div>
<div>Sm</div>
<div>Eu</div>
<div>Gd</div>
<div>Tb</div>
<div>Dy</div>
<div>Ho</div>
<div>Er</div>
<div>Tm</div>
<div>Yb</div>
<div>Lu</div>
<div>Ac</div>
<div>Th</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes "" in your link - refer to the mentioned link for further details 
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

```
<div><a href="https://www.google.com/">Nd</a></div>
```

Comment: Nothing seem to have happened, thank you for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

Just provide double quote ;) and do not close your tag so quickly ;)

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Nd</a>
```

If you want to be perfect, provide a "target" attribute to.

_self for your current tab,
_blank for a new tab

So,

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Nd</a>
```

should be perfect ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `content` rule from your css for div. Quotes are not so improtant but add it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can click it because the `div:before` pseudo element in position "absolute" is covering up the link, try to add this rules:

```
div:before {
   z-index: 10;
}

div > a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

with the link in position relative you can set a z-index greater than the :before elements, and you should be able to click it.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

This code works! check your syntax for [a](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) html tag.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: chocolate;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
div:hover:before {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com"><div>Nd</div></a>
<div>Pm</div>
<div>Sm</div>
<div>Eu</div>
<div>Gd</div>
<div>Tb</div>
<div>Dy</div>
<div>Ho</div>
<div>Er</div>
<div>Tm</div>
<div>Yb</div>
<div>Lu</div>
<div>Ac</div>
<div>Th</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:before` is overlapping on `<a>` tag

Add `position: relative` and `z-index:` 1 to `a`

```
a {
 position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: chocolate;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
div:hover:before {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0);
}
a {
 position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div><a href=https://www.google.com/>Nd</a></div>
<div>Pm</div>
<div>Sm</div>
<div>Eu</div>
<div>Gd</div>
<div>Tb</div>
<div>Dy</div>
<div>Ho</div>
<div>Er</div>
<div>Tm</div>
<div>Yb</div>
<div>Lu</div>
<div>Ac</div>
<div>Th</div>
```

Comment: I'm finally able to click the hyperlink. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `content: "";` from  `div::before`
Now its working fine

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: chocolate;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
div:hover:before {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0);
}
```

```html
<div><a href="https://www.google.com/" style="z-index:999;">Nd</a></div>
<div>Pm</div>
<div>Sm</div>
<div>Eu</div>
<div>Gd</div>
<div>Tb</div>
<div>Dy</div>
<div>Ho</div>
<div>Er</div>
<div>Tm</div>
<div>Yb</div>
<div>Lu</div>
<div>Ac</div>
<div>Th</div>
```